# How to find which app is in foreground with appium

Tags: python, appium

I am automating mobile app using python and appium, where we have to launch maps application(Google maps and Apple maps).

Is there any way to know which is the current active app in foreground by using Appium?

I can do it using shell commands for Android. But, how can I validate if Apple maps is launched or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS, you can use `self.driver.session['CFBundleIdentifier']`:

```
def close_and_open_app(self):
    package_name = self.driver.session['CFBundleIdentifier']
    self.driver.terminate_app(package_name)
    self.driver.activate_app(package_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for android [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/current-activity/)

```
self.driver.current_activity
```

For iOS, I ended up doing negative validation of looking for element in my application under test(AUT). So, I am making sure some unique element in my AUT is not visible on the screen.